# Correct way to hide a fragment that is reusable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in my app that shows information when a item from a map is clicked.

When you click the marker, from the bottom, sliding up, appears this fragment. If the fragment is already there, first it slides down with the "old" informarion and then slides up with the new one. But you can hide this information fragment, for example, when you click on a typical center in location button.

The problem:

When I click in this "center in location" button, simply, I hide the fragment:

```
@Override
public void hideInfoBanner() {
    if (infoFrameLayout != null){
        infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

So, when I click on another mark (or the same):

```
private void loadInfoFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        infoBannerFragmentTansaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        infoBannerFragmentTansaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.slide_down_out_anim);

        infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (infoBannerFragmentTansaction == null) {
            infoBannerFragmentTansaction.add(R.id.map_wifispot_info_banner, fragment);
        } else {
            infoBannerFragmentTansaction.replace(R.id.map_wifispot_info_banner, fragment);
        }

        infoBannerFragmentTansaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

The old (and hidden) fragment momentarily, appears, slides down, and then slides up with the new information. I don't want it to appear momentarily, just slide up with the new information.

I suppose I am "breaking" the fragment lifecycle hidding it. And when I call it again, firstly it ends what it was doing...

So, how can I hide a fragment ending it's lifecycle?

Comment: try not using fragmentTransaction.add(). Just remove that if - else and just use replace

Comment: I removed add() and I am using replace() but it still does the annoying appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not breaking any lifecycle. Your fragments behave like you set. on Change it makes out animation, replace, and make it animation like in your code. If you wanna set only in animation when fragment is not visible simple add a condition for it

```
if(infoFrameLayout.getVisability()==View.GONE){

    infoBannerFragmentTansaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.your_custom_animation_to_hide_it_in_0_milis);
}else{

    infoBannerFragmentTansaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.slide_down_out_anim);
}
```

EDIT:

Hey, i have made exit animation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate">
    <alpha
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="0"
        />

</set>
```

And it works like a charm

Comment: Isn´t any better way to avoid the appearence? I don't want to create an anim only to patch.

Comment: set old fragment view alpha to 0

Comment: I tried the code  of your answer and it doesn't work :(. It only shows the fragment for a instant and disappears, of course without the animation.

Comment: but what is a problem to create new animation?

Comment: No, there is no problem. I tried your code. I have added a new animation with duration="0" but the problem persist.

Comment: ok. when the fragment is gone try to `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame)).commit();` before

Comment: But it will throw a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called" Exception, right?

Comment: sincerely i dont know. I will try it later on, because it makes me wonder ;P